# Automatic display detection not working correctly anymore on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, updates, display

Is there a way to check history of all updates automatically installed by "Software & Updates"?

Today after updating some packages, automatic detection of connected displays was somehow changed. I am not able to use my T520+docking with additional 2 displays anymore (means triple heads all together). It was working before today's updates.

How to check history of automatic updates (today's updates list) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Ubuntu Software Center -> History tab (third icon from top-left) -> Updates.